# Knife cleaning: safe to do without soap?

Tags: food-safety, cleaning, knives

[*Knife Skills Illustrated: A User's Manual*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393061787) suggests that knives can be cleaned with hot running water alone. "With sufficiently hot water, soap should not be necessary." Is this safe? What if I am only cutting vegetables? What if I am also cutting raw meat?

Comment: Why does the book want to avoid soap? I mean, yes, in theory, with hot enough water and appropriate scrubbing to remove any particulates you could be OK (though I'm not clear that most residential hot water systems are actually hot enough for that), but why not use soap? It helps move things along and get things off the knife. What's the supposed advantage to to not using it?

Comment: The book doesn't go into any detail on why one would not want to use soap.

Comment: Regardless of safety (=killing bacteria), water cannot dissolve fat, while soapy water can. If you don't use soap, your knives will stay greasy, smearing old rancid fat on anything new you cut with them.

Comment: Note that the book does not say "avoid" or "do not use" soap. It says soap "should not be necessary". Hot water can make fats melt or dissolve so they can slide off the knife. Soap, in itself, does not sanitize anything. Something can be clean but not sanitary and sanitary but not clean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to "Sanitize" any surface you must wash that surface (in this case, knife blades) with water at no less than 190°F (~88°C) according to the (U.S.A) National Sanitation Foundation (NSF). Earlier this year the [Conference for Food Protection](http://www.foodprotect.org/) recommended [reducing that standard to 160°F (~71°C)](http://www.foodprotect.org/biennial-meeting/issues/2010Packet/issues/III_007.html) as an "energy saving measure" citing a study at Ohio University that claims that it is equally effective. Additionally they recommended that the temperature could be reduced to 120°F (~49°C) with 'chemical additives' (soap).

So the question is "How hot is your hot running water?" According to "[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_heating)" *(a dubious source at times, but I will accept it for this point)* suggests that most home water heaters produce water at 104°F (~40°C) to 120°F (~49°C). This would suggest that to sanitize a knife blade **something more than 'hot running water' is necessary**. In fact since water over 131°F (~55°C) puts you at risk for scalding (Wikipedia, Ibid) and you certainly don't want a water heater putting out water that hot, I would have to disagree with your source and conclude that ***in household use soap is required to sanitize your knife blade***.

note: in order to qualify my answer to the question of "safe", I have elevated the standard from "clean" to "sanitized", certainly you may 'clean' a knife with running water but that level of clean is not what I would consider 'safe'.

Comment: You could, of course, always heat the water in a pot.

Comment: Yes, Bob, you could. But the QUESTION was about "hot running water" ;)

Comment: FYI, According to this new article http://www.mysundaynews.com/2011/06/02/tip-18-setting-the-water-heater-temperature/, the US DOE is recommending 120F at the tap.

Comment: Even if it is *actually* at that *recommended* temp, 120°F is insufficient to sanitize without additives.

Comment: With a funnel you could turn water heater in a pot (or microwave) into "hot running water"...

Comment: Somehow I believe that begins to stray from OP's intentions.

Comment: +1, standard procedure should be 1. soap, 2. hot water & 3. dry with paper towel.

Comment: "According to "Wikipedia" (a dubious source at times,..." scoff-scoff condescending.

Comment: -1 [Soap does not kill germs.](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/30094/14563) -- actually your answer prompted me to ask that question.  I'm still hoping there's a proper answer to the question of how to clean a knife.

Comment: @alx9r, "Soap" is a common term for a lot of things. Most common kitchen soaps (such as 'Dawn') contain added chemicals which are 'anti-bacterial' and which do actually does _remove_ germs and other bacteria. Frankly, your [other question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/30094/6279) is a 'step in the wrong direction'.

Comment: @CosCallis - With respect, understanding the difference between cleaning (i.e. removing germs and the substances that culture them) and sanitizing (i.e. killing germs in place) is essential to food safety.  I don't see how a factual discussion about that difference is a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @CosCallis - With respect to the efficacy of 'anti-bacterial' soap sanitizing (i.e. killing germs), there doesn't seem to be conclusive evidence that they indeed kill germs any better than regular soap.  [This WebMD article](http://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/news/20070817/plain-soap-as-good-as-antibacterial), for example, cites a study that found the antibacterial properties of regular and 'anti-bacterial' soap to be about the same.  Furthermore, the term 'anti-bacterial' makes no claim about killing foodborne viruses which ought also to be a concern when cleaning knives.